# Getting NoSuchProviderException while sending emails using parallel stream

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, jakarta-mail

I am sending emails to the list of users using Java 8's parallel stream. Here is my code -

```
AtomicInteger numberOfMailSent = new AtomicInteger(0);
listUsers.parallelStream().forEach(recipient -> {
    try {
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
        if (EmailHelper.sendEmail(recipient.getEmailAddress()) == true) 
            numberOfMailSent.incrementAndGet();         
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        logger.error("An error in sending email due to - " + e1.getMessage());
}});    
System.out.println(numberOfMailSent);
```

In the above code sendEmail method uses Java Mail API version 1.4.0 (I don't have the source code). The list of users has about 20-40 users and it depends on other inputs. For some of the users in the list this code throws -

```
NoSuchProviderException: No provider for Address type: rfc822
javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for Address type: rfc822
     at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:475)
     at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:154)
     at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:80)
```

But when I run the same list of users using for each loop sequentially, I don't get this error at all and the mail goes fine. I have tried changing the Java mail api version to 1.4.7 but no success. Any idea anyone on why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: Show us the stacktrace.

Comment: @StephenC - Updated

Comment: The code that you have shown us **cannot** produce that stacktrace.   But I suspect that the problem is a race condition in the initialization of the `javax.mail.Session` object that your (real) code is using.